# Interfacing a 3.3 V output to 5 V inputs

Tags: voltage, fpga

I have a [BASYS3 board](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/basys3:basys3_rm.pdf) which outputs 3.3 V, however, my [PIR sensor](https://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf) works with 5 V. I also have a [5 V power supply](https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/3-3v-5v-breadboard-guc-karti-datasheet.pdf) but I'm not sure how to connect these three.

I don't want to damage my BASYS3 as well so I'm reluctant to try anything. How can I connect these three on my breadboard?

Edit: This is what I'd like to do:

[image]

But the sensor does not work with BASYS3's 3.3 V output. Normally it does not work when I try to connect Vcc and ground pins to the 5 V power supply and the output pin to the FPGA.

Comment: Show what you'd like to connect pictorially and link to the device data sheets.

Comment: @Andyaka i edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the datasheet of your PIR, it requires 5V (4.5 to 20) as power supply, but its logic output is 3.3V, which seems the same level of your BASYS board.

So, definitely you can safely connect them provided the following:

1. Connect all the GNDs of every device together. As mentioned in another answer, two devices can communicate only when sharing a common reference.
2. Find a +5V somewhere to give power to your PIR. If the BASYS board has a power output of +5V, you can use that and you are done.
3. If your BASYS device does not have a +5V output, then you need another power supply. In this case, even 12V would do (the PIR accepts from 4.5 to 20 volt). The power supply has a GND pin and a +V pin. Again, connect the GND pin to the two GND pins of the two other devices. The +V pin goes in the only place it can go: the +PowerIN of the pir.

ANOTHER THING: when using logic (digital) levels, you can always put resistors in between. For example, you have to connect an output to an input? Well, connect them via a 1k resistor, it will work the same but it will not fry your devices in case of errors. Resistor values range normally from 100 ohm to even 10k, depending on the application, internal resistance (or impedence) of input and output, but 1k should always work. If it does not work, at least you do no damage.

FORGOT to say: probably a 3.3V output drives correctly a 5V input anyway - it is the contrary that can be problematic (but in this last case a resistor can do, even if it is not the most beautiful solution).

Comment: thank you very much! you saved my day :) can't thank you enough for this well detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the TL'DR

1. Use a single 5V external power supply for simplicity and ditch the USB, power the FIR and the FPGA off that, problem solved.
2. Alternatively a more hackish single-supply solution is to power your FIR off the middle pin of JP6 and power both the FIR and FPGA from USB power.
3. The most complex solution is do what your currently doing but bridge the ground on the FPGA with the ground on the power supply, then use the power supply to power the FIR and connect the logic pin as normal.
4. No matter which of the top three solutions you decide on there is no need for you to add any logic level conversion between the FIR and the FPGA, the voltage level is already appropriate.

Your setup where you power the PIR off of 5V and use the output as a digital logic to the FPGA board is, in theory, the correct approach. The PIR's output logic level is 3.3V so this works just fine, since this hasnt worked for you there are a few possibilities to consider.

First off your FPGA board doesn't really provide a regulated 5V voltage source, which means you will need to use the one your supplied if you want a nice clean output. That is the best way to go. However what I would do to make this as minimalistic as possible is to use the power supply you have linked in 5V mode to power your FPGA board directly rather than powering it off USB or a different external power supply. To do this you would connect the power supply to JP6 and you would configure JP2 to EXT. This will ensure the ground connection provided by your FPGA board is connected to the ground from the power supply. At that point you can hook up the PIR to the ground from any point you want and the +Vcc to your power supplies output. This eliminates the need for two seperate power supplies. The other option which is a little hacky but should work well enough is you could power the FPGA from a USB power supply (which tend to be relatively clean) and then tap into that to power your FIR by wiring the +Vcc to the middle connector of JP6 on the FPGA board. This would eliminate the need for the external power board.

The reason your own setup didnt work is, I suspect, because you wired the FIR's power directly to the power supply you lited, but then powered the FPGA from a different power supply. This results in what we call a floating ground where the ground potential of your FIR and the ground potential of your FPGA could be significantly different and cause things to break. If for some reason you wanted to use two seperate power supplies rather than the simplified single power supply I suggested you can still do that, but in that case you would need to have a wire physically connected the ground on the FPGA board to the ground on your secondary power supply.

Keep in mind because of the way you wired your board already there is a possibility you fried something, so if the above doesnt work you should consider the fact that one of the components may not need to be replace.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally it does not work when I try to connect vcc and ground pins to the 5v power supply and the output pin to the fpga.

It probably needs the same GND.

Answer (score 0):

If I have the room my first choice when doing level shifting from 3V3 to 5V is to use 74HCT devices, they work great and give me some current so I can drive several loads with the output. For input on 3V3 I use 74C914 or 74HC914, no resistors or anything else needed for higher voltages in the +-25V range. These devices are not that expensive. There are other logic devices that will do this and it helps to keep outside noise from the processor.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it depends very much on the HW and peripherials that you are using in your design. But I actually managed to move a low consumption servo motor (SG90) with Basys3 board. The guidelines I used were the following:

- I used the same supply line for the FPGA, and the servo.
- Of course I did the same for the ground line (GND).
- And I used one of the PMOD pins of the board to control the servo motor.

To explain the details, I took one of my old micro USB cables along with an old mobile transformer which gave me fair enough power to supply the FPGA (roughly 2 Watts), and the servomotor. Of course I had to scratch this micro USB cable and draw out the two lines to supply my electronic devices.

Servomotors and many peripherials work with TTL standards which means that a 3.3 V is more than enough to control your peripherial as long as your sensor is wired to its correct voltage at its supply line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).